# Find $x-\sqrt{7x}$ given that $x - \sqrt{\frac7x}=8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, roots, radicals, substitution

> If $ x - \sqrt{\frac{7}{x}}=8$ then $x-\sqrt{7x}=\text{?}$

I used some ways, but couldn't get the right form :) by the way, the answer is $1$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any thoughts by yourself?

Comment: I used some ways but couldn't get the right form :) by the way the answer is 1.

Comment: I edited the question to separate the problem statement from your own work on the problem.  Can you please fill in the work you've done and where you got stuck?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: As i said before my own work gave no result, i used some ways but couldn't find the right path. I am not the guy that only needs the answers as you can see my profile, at least a tip could be handy, thanks for you attention :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $x=7y^2,$ where $y>0$.

Thus, $$7y^2-\frac{1}{y}=8$$ or
$$7y^3-8y-1=0$$ or
$$7y^3+7y^2-7y^2-7y-y-1=0$$ or
$$(y+1)(7y^2-7y-1)=0.$$
Thus,
$$x-\sqrt{7x}=7y^2-7y=1.$$
Done!

Answer (score 5):

\begin{eqnarray*}
x-\sqrt{\frac{7}{x}}=8 \\
x-8 =\sqrt{\frac{7}{x}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now square both sides and multiply by $x$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2-16x+64=\frac{7}{x} \\
x^3-16x^2+64x-7=0 \\
(x-7)(x^2-9x+1)=0
\end{eqnarray*}
Now assume $x$ does not equal $7$ and taking the positive square root will give
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2-9x+1=0 \\
x^2-2x+1= 7x \\
(x-1)^2 =7x \\
x-1 = \sqrt{7x} \\
x-\sqrt{7x}= \color{red}{1}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: No need to assume that $x \neq 7$, since we know that is the case from the initial equation.