# Inequality $\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{\frac{a}{a+8}} \geq 1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, uvw

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc = 1$. Prove that 
>   $$\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \sqrt{\frac{a}{a+8}} \geq 1.$$

I have tried using some substitutions but still cannot do it. Please suggest.

Comment: I don't think that it's not so duplicate because at least one of my solutions different than solution in the linked topic.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg BTW by using (at)Martin instead of (at)MartinR you pinged me - my guess is that this was not what you intended. I think that you have participated in a few discussions about duplicates - so you already know that closing a post as a duplicated does not delete the answers.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347703 With duplicates sometimes happens the similar thing. I'll get an example. I did not ping you. Why do you speak to  me with this tone?